# Is PoE AND PoE+ possible with a Cat. 6a cable? (Cable description below)

Tags: ethernet, power, cable, cat6, power-over-ethernet

This is the cable I would like to take:
Dätwyler UNINET 7060 4P FRNC/LS0H (100m, Orange, S/FTP, Kat. 6a)

I got another question, is it possible to connect non-poe devices and poe devices to a PoE+ switch? Or will blow this up.

Answer (score 1):

PoE only provides 25.5W at max to devices. The IEEE standards for PoE require category 5 cable or better. So a Category 6a is fairly future proof for both power supply and data rate. The standard and it's requirements are outlined [here](https://www.ieee.li/pdf/viewgraphs/introduction_to_poe_802.3af_802.3at.pdf).

To answer the question about hooking non-PoE device up to a PoE switch, it doesn't matter. The switch will send a low voltage signal down the power pairs, and unless the resistance is perfect, no power will be provided.

A powered device indicates that it is standards-compliant by placing a 25 kΩ resistor between the powered pairs. If the power supply equipment detects a resistance that is too high or too low (including a short circuit), no power is applied. To stay powered, the powered device must continuously use 5–10 mA for at least 60 ms with no more than 400 ms since last use or else it will be unpowered by the power supply equipment.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_over_Ethernet#Powering_devices